# Нет связи между двумя виртуальными серверами Ubuntu из разных подсетей

Tags: сеть, виртуальная-машина, подсети

Вопрос банальный, но моих знаний оказалось недостаточно.
Вот топология сети:
[image: Топология]

При выполнении команды ping с первого сервера (192.168.1.2) на ip 172.16.1.1, пакеты отправляются. При попытке пропинговать 172.16.1.2 ничего не выходит.
Аналогично и со вторым сервером, с него могу пропинговать 192.168.1.1, но не 192.168.1.2

Вот настройки сети для 1-го сервера (192.168.1.2):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для десктопной Ubuntu с IDS/IPS:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И настройки второго сервера (172.16.1.2):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понимаю, что вопрос глупый, возможно не хватает дополнительно прописанного пути?
Как мне настроить связь между двумя серверами через десктопную убунту?

Машины стоят на VMWare, сервера в разных LAN-ах, на десктопной убунте два сетевых адаптера, каждый из которых смотрит в LAN с нужным сервером.

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

Для десктопной Ubuntu, нужно  разрешить транзитный трафик в /etc/sysctl.conf, настроить firewall и либо автоматическую трансляцию адресов, либо маршрутизацию, либо строить сетевой мост в зависимости от задачи.